# Is there a way to change "extend" value of the original component you are extending?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

There is a standard `filefield` component:

```
Ext.define('Ext.form.field.File', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text',
    ...
});
```

I want to make my own file field component with the only difference that it is based on `Ext.form.field.TextArea` instead of `Ext.form.field.Text`.

Is there an efficient way of doing it without copying the full original component source and changing one line?

Comment: Nope, there isn't. The base component has been chosen for a reason (a good reason, I hope). What added functionality do you expect in a `filefield` that extends from `textareafield`?

Comment: @Alexander I will be adding some extra functionality, I just wanted to start with the file component instead of making my own copy and duplicating all its methods.